# How to get difference in given time and current time in typescript is

Tags: angular, typescript, date, angular7

I am using angular 7 and want to display elements in component html if following condition is satisfied: given time is ahead of current time.

I tried below logic

```
 getTimeDiff(time, date)
    {

         const dateNow = new Date()
         const slotDate = new Date(`${date} ${time}`);  // say time = '10:30:00' and date = '2018-11-14' 

         const diff = Math.abs(Math.abs(dateNow.getTime() - slotDate.getTime()) /  3600000)

        //if diff is not negative
       if(diff) {
         return false
      } 
        else {
         return true
       }
     }
```

HTML

```
<span *ngIf="getTimeDiff(result.endtime, result.date)"> open </span>
```

**Update**

Elements are displayed  using *ngFor so I cannot call getTimeDiff in ngOnInit().

```
<div *ngFor="let result of results">
    <span *ngIf="getTimeDiff(result.endtime, result.date)"> open </span>
</div>
```

but for some reason I get:

> ViewAppointmentsComponent.html:30 ERROR Error:
>   ExpressionChangedAfterItHasBeenCheckedError: Expression has changed
>   after it was checked. Previous value: 'null: 6.0732225'. Current
>   value: 'null: 6.0732252777777775'.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That's a lifecycle error, saying Angular has already checked a value, but you're updating it for some reason.

If you put a console log in your function, you will see that it's called **A LOT** of time.

That's because functions, bound to directives, are called at every user interaction.

That means that everytime it's called, it gets a new date value (+1 ms)

To avoid that, create your date at component creation and compare on it. If you wish, you can update it some time, but not in the function itself.

```
constructor(private now = new Date()) {}

getTimeDiff(time, date)
{
     const slotDate = new Date(`${date} ${time}`);  // say time = '10:30:00' and date = '2018-11-14' 

     const diff = Math.abs(Math.abs(this.now.getTime() - slotDate.getTime()) /  3600000)

    //if diff is not negative
   if(diff) {
     return false
  } 
    else {
     return true
   }
 }
```

#### EDIT

To avoid your function being called, you could use a variable that is update on change :

```
this.timeDiff: boolean;

ngDoCheck() {
  this.timeDiff(this.result.endtime, this.result.date);
}

getTimeDiff(time, date)
{
     const slotDate = new Date(`${date} ${time}`);  // say time = '10:30:00' and date = '2018-11-14' 

     const diff = Math.abs(Math.abs(this.now.getTime() - slotDate.getTime()) /  3600000)

    //if diff is not negative
   if(diff) {
     this.timeDiff = false;
  } 
    else {
     this.timeDiff =  true;
   }
 }
```

In your HTML

```
<span *ngIf="timeDiff"> open </span>
```

`ngDoCheck` is a lifecycle hook (like `ngOnInit`) that can be summed up by

> Function that detect changes that are not tracked by Angular

Comment: Thanks trichetriche. I was very confused due to multiple log. Now I have shifted private now = new Date() to scope of component but still get console several times. Though error is gone.

Comment: The console log will always appear, I have given you the way to avoid the lifecycle error, not to change the Angular lifecycle itself :) And your syntax (component member) and mine (constructor parameter with access modifier) are the same, it's just that mine is a shortcut, so use the one you prefer, it won't change much !

Comment: trichetriche Can I do something so that getTimeDiff function does not keep on executing. As I have to add some more logic to it , like setting up some flag true and as it keeps on executing again and again that flags again set to true even if I have later set it to false. This does not happen with other functions which does not involve time. Thanks.

Comment: @Simer Sure, I have edited my answer, feel free to try it out

Answer (score 1):

`Angular` runs change detection and when its find that some values which has been passed to the child component has been changed Angular throws the error `ExpressionChangedAfterItHasBeenCheckedError`.

Better to create one variable to hold the information rather than calling the same function on each change detection

```
different = false;  //<-- hold the difference state.

getTimeDiff(time, date)
{

     const dateNow = new Date()
     const slotDate = new Date(`${date} ${time}`);  // say time = '10:30:00' and date = '2018-11-14' 

     const diff = Math.abs(Math.abs(dateNow.getTime() - slotDate.getTime()) /  3600000)

    //if diff is not negative
   if(diff) {
     this.different = false  //<-- change to false.
  } 
    else {
     this.different  = true  //<-- change to true.
   }
 }
```

### html

```
<span *ngIf="different"> open </span>
```

> Note : Do not forget to call getTimeDiff function in appropriate place like ngOnInit if you want to get one time .

Comment: I have to call getTimeDiff in *ngFor. Let me update my question.

Comment: With this, the error will not disappear, as the process is the same : the `dateNow` will get updated at every millisecond, resulting in the same error encountered by OP.